# Conditional restart of supervisord processes?

Tags: supervisord

I've been using supervisord for a while -- outstanding tool.  The one use case I haven't been able to figure out is, how to configure jobs to be restarted until a condition is met, then stop restarting.

Example: let's say you have a bunch of work to do, like scaling thousands of images, or servicing millions of requests on a queue.  A useful pattern would be to run many workers in parallel to work on that backlog.  You could set up a supervisord job that ensures 100 workers are running, and if any of them crash, supervisord will spin up replacements so the pool of workers won't shrink.

That's great until the work is done.  Maybe when the backlog is gone, the number of workers should scale down to 1 or 0. Supervisord will keep spinning up the total to be 100 processes, even if each new process checks to see if there's work to be done, sees none, and shuts down very quickly.

Is there a way for a process instance or process family to communicate with supervisord to say, the autoretsart behavior is no longer needed?  Better yet, is there a way to scale the number of worker processes up and down based on some condition (like number of files in a directory or ??).

I know it can be done by updating the `supervisord.conf` file and running `supervisorctl reload`, but I'd prefer something that's more declarative and self-managing if such a thing exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way for a process instance or process family to communicate with supervisord to say, the autoretsart behavior is no longer needed?

You can wind down an activity by making sure your processes exit with different exitcode(s) when there is no work and making those the expected [`exitcodes`](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html?highlight=exitcodes#program-x-section-example) with [`autorestart=unexpected`](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html?highlight=unexpected#program-x-section-example) in the configuration.

> Better yet, is there a way to scale the number of worker processes up and down based on some condition (like number of files in a directory or ??).

The trouble is that the automatic [state transitions](http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html?highlight=unexpected#process-states) don't allow for getting processes running again from an expected `EXITED` state. AFAIK the only way to do this is with the XML-RPC API's [`startProcess`](http://supervisord.org/api.html#supervisor.rpcinterface.SupervisorNamespaceRPCInterface.startProcess), so you would need to write or find an appropriate event listener that watches for your start condition and then uses the API.

An alternate design is to wrap your worker process in an event handler watching [PROCESS COMMUNICATION Events](http://supervisord.org/events.html#process-communication-event-type) and have one normal subprocess communicating new tasks to a pool of event listeners. But that model doesn't currently eliminate a pool of waiting processes when there is no work, it just organizes the control task in a way that may make it easier to separate out task related logic and resource usage.